# JS for loop where value is defined yet get TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, for-loop, typeerror

most of the searches on SO were Angular related issues but this is native node.js.  I have a data set array that I make an API call for then I want to iterate over a range of the array in which the array[0] will always increment up.

My Function to to sum up the values in an array or arrays for a passed in range:

```
  function sum(arr, level){
    var end = parseFloat(arr[0][0]) + level;
    //console.log(arr[0][0], end);
    var newArr = [];
    for (var i=0; parseFloat(arr[i][0]) < end; i++){
    newArr.push(parseFloat(arr[i][1]));
  }
    return newArr.reduce((a,b) => a+b);
  }
```

my API call which receives the array of arrays without issue then I call my function which gets the array undefined error that I pass into it. (see below).   This leverages the GDAX Libary...

```
const Gdax = require('../node_modules/gdax');
const publicClient = new Gdax.PublicClient();

    setInterval(function(){
      publicClient.getProductOrderBook('ETH-USD',{ level: 3 },(error, response, 
book) => {
      var bidTotal = sum(book['bids'], 10);
      var askTotal = sum(book['asks'], 10);
    });
}, 2000);
```

The call returns gets an array or arrays as a response, example:

```
    [ [ '922.03', '3.3889', '5be95c88-b0a9-4a85-b89f-c067a4ee2364' ],
  [ '922.03', '0.01', '78183ddc-458d-4db0-96b1-a2b63381ae67' ],
  [ '921.77', '0.05', '5aec1e1b-ff19-4572-a2b9-8ee6e5ad3267' ],
  [ '921.7', '0.1003062', '9f73bbfe-615e-4ab3-9318-d08fd9719c81' ],
  [ '921.7', '0.11206032', '6ab33d08-20eb-4832-9e13-b9ff3ed2454c' ] ]
```

My sum function can console.log arr[0][0] so it is defined however when the for loop starts it becomes undefined?  I am thinking it's to do with JavaScript's async nature but I have no idea why it wont work when the array is defined...

```
/home/ubuntu/workspace/gdax/server1.js:57
  for (var i=0; parseFloat(arr[i][0]) < end; i++){
                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: What's this suppose to do `var end = parseFloat(arr[0][0]) + level`? It makes your loop with 5 elements run for 922 times and it fails at 6th

Comment: my array is actually 34,000 elements long, I cut it short for example.  So the start is the first number and each items in the arr[i][0] goes up.  I only want the first value plus $10 worth of data, i don't need it all so this is to get a range.  SO i want to iterate until the arr[i][0] is reached which I set as my end point of the first value + 10...

Comment: My point was, your limit value is wrong. You should try to resolve it

Comment: Why so complicated? `const sum = arr.reduce( ( sum, next ) => sum += parseFloat( next[0], 10 ), 0.00 );`  If you only need certain numbers of the 34k elements, filter the array before reducting it. `arr.filter( ticker => ticker.level === ??? );`

Comment: its still getting undefined though, complicated I guess because I am not a developer, just a amateur trying to script some data I will use

Answer (score 0):

Your index i can become bigger than the actual length of your array if you just give it this condition to end

```
parseFloat(arr[i][0]) < end
```

So you need to iterate through the array of arrays using their lengths as the condition to end.
Then you can compare the value inside the loop with your `var end =parseFloat(arr[0][0]) + level;`

Comment: But then the array loops 34,000 times every two seconds, isn't that inefficient?  How can we kill the loop when it hits the "end" condition we specify?

Comment: if your end condition is true just break out of the loop using the break; statement